# Vuforia with multiple scenes in unity doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have 4 scenes in my unity android app. Main menu, QR code (ARcore recognition), Sliders (were I just have my robot in and move the joints), and Vuforia scene. Now the issue is if I build the app to run the vuforia scene first, vuforia works and the model target recognition works. But as soon as I switch the scene it never works again. Why is that and can it be fixed. If I can provide any additional info just tell me how and what. Thanks in advance

I tried the solution offered at the vuforia page:
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/using-arcore-vuforia-engine
But I don't have the tracking mode and ARcore requirement options.

I am using unity 2022.3.11f1 and vuforia 10-19-3 on an android 14 Samsung s23 ultra one ui6

Comment: I would check the Android logcat (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat) for error messages from Vuforia SDK. Does Vuforia stop working after switching to any scene or just after switching to the QR code one? Vuforia also uses ARCore, it is possible that the QR code scene does not release the resource and Vuforia cannot use it. One possible workaround would be to use Vuforia own QR code scanner https://developer.vuforia.com/library/objects/barcode-scanner .